# What is the procedure to convert binary file to image?

Tags: image, malware, kaggle

like in Microsoft malware Big(2015) challenge can anyone share code on how to convert binary to image format. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert binary file to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092289/convert-binary-file-to-image)

Comment: Your question is far too vague for Stack Overflow.